# What is the geometrical difference between concave function and Strictly concave funciton?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function
According to the wikipedia article, a function f is said to be concave for any x and y and for any $ \alpha \in [0,1]$, the following holds:
$ f((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y) \geq (1-\alpha)f(x) + \alpha y$.

I can imagine in two dimensional space that a line between any two points of the function is below the function value.
So, as shown in the wikipedia picture, the line has two cross points b/w the function and clearly when $\alpha= 0, 1$, the inequality becomes f(x) = f(x) or f(y) = f(y)

And the function is called strictly concave if

$ f((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y) > (1-\alpha)f(x) + \alpha y$ holds
 for any $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $x\neq y$.

What is the pictorial difference between non-strictly concave and strictly concave function?
What happens in the picture in the wikipedia for strict case?
I could not get the point from [Visual difference between strictly concave and not strictly concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376690/visual-difference-between-strictly-concave-and-not-strictly-concave)

Answer (score 2):

A line is concave, but not strictly concave.  Consequently, the graph of a concave function can include linear segments, but the graph of a strictly concave function cannot contain a linear segment.  For instance, the following graph is of a concave function, but that function is not strictly concave.

𝝠